# I want to submit HTML form into mysql DB using Java MVC framwork. I cannot access file from the HTML page

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, modelattribute

FORM:

```
<form action='/ticketDataCollector/' method='post'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Attachment</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='file' name='attachment'>
        </td>
    </tr>
...
```

`ticketDataCollector` method signature:

```
public ModelAndView ticketDataCollector(@ModelAttribute("ticketObject") Ticket ticketObject)
```

Ticket is java class:

```
private File attachment;

public File getAttachment(){
    return attachment
}
```

`getAttachment()` returns `null` when I select a file on the HTML page.
Is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: Thank you Gazeciarz, i managed to upload the image into DB, but when i retrieve the image from DB it come as "java.io.BufferedOutputStream@16f91c8" . I am not sure if i am uploading the image properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure MultiPartResolver and change content type to multipart/form-data in Your html form. See example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/
And i think that spring will not autowire file in Your model. You need to do it manually..

Comment: Thank you @Gazeciarz, i managed to upload image into DB, but when i retrieve it from DB it come as "java.io.BufferedOutputStream@16f91c8" . I am not sure if i am uploading the image properly. Following is my code for uploading and displaying image from DB.      
doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam("attachment") MultipartFile filePart){
     InputStream input = filePart.getInputStream();
     byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(input); 
 preparedStat = con.prepareStatement( "insert into "+tableName+" (Id,Screenshot) values (default,\""+image+"\")");

Comment: my doGet method --
    if (resultFromQuery.next()) {
                 java.sql.Blob blob = resultFromQuery.getBlob("Screenshot");
                 InputStream inputStream = blob.getBinaryStream();
                 OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                 int bytesRead = -1;
                 while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                     outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                 }